# Is it possible to make a collapsing variables without making individual functions?

Tags: function, variables, lua

I have a code that starts as a small amount of variables and makes more elements using those initial variables.

```
function new( x, y, width, height )
    local object = {}
    --border
    object.border = { x = x, y = y, width = width, height = height }
    --body
    object.body = { x = x+1, y = y+1, width = width-2, height = height-2 }
    --font
    object.font = {}
    object.font.size = (object.body.height+2)-(math.floor((object.body.height+2)/4)+1)
    object.font.height = love.graphics.setNewFont( object.font.size ):getHeight()
    --padding
    object.padding = {}
    object.padding.height = math.floor(object.border.height*(2/29))
    object.padding.width = object.padding.height*3
    --text
    object.text = { input = '' }
    object.text.centerHeight = math.ceil(object.body.y+((object.body.height-object.font.height)/2))
    object.text.left = object.body.x+object.padding.width+object.padding.height
    --backspacing
    object.backspace = {key = false, rate = 3, time = 0, pausetime = 20, pause = true}
    --config
    object.config = { active = true, devmode = false, debug = false, id = gui.id(), type = 'textbox' }
    gui.add(object)
    return object.config.id
end
```

and when I modify something in the middle part, the whole thing becomes a mess because starting from the one i changed until the bottom ones value doesn't agree with each other

```
local x = gui.get(2)
x.body.height = 50
```

I'm looking if there's a way for these variables to be redefined, starting from them until the bottom, without: (a) making functions for each of the variables. and (b) editing the required parameters in the function.

and If there's none, are the an alternate way to do this efficiently?

EDIT:
the structure of the variables is as follow:

```
border->body->padding->font
```

what i needed is a way i can define **any** of them so that the one that follows also changes like:

```
object.body.x = 15
```

and it would collapse from that redefined variable until the bottom:

```
body->padding->font
```

i could just redefine them from the edited variable until the bottom like this:

```
--not the actual code, just an example of variables dependent on the variable above
object.body.x = 15
object.padding.width = object.body.x+1
object.font.size = object.padding.width+1
```

but that means I have to do the same when redefining the padding until the font which is extremely inefficient especially when I extended more elements.

example:

```
--padding->font
object.padding.width = 5
object.font.size = object.padding.width+1
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here. What kinds of modifications "in the middle part" cause things to "become a mess". Give us an example.

Comment: @NicolBolas I gave an example at the bottom part, all my variables are stored in a local and are accessed using the gui.get() and gui.add() and such. what i mean by in the middle part is when i for example change the body.height element, i also wanted to change the text.left element  as it is also defined using the body.height. Sort of like a domino effect that collapses when you affect something but only in a single direction and not everything.

Comment: You can use __newindex and a proxy table...

Comment: what I simply needed is like how the goto works in C++ but that's not available in lua and I would need to make a function that edits the var starting from the change until the bottom, (for every dynamic variables). so 1 long function for redefining a dynamic variables so the bottom ones also changes which is very impractical. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was bored and saw this question *(again)* along with a duplicate.
I started writing some code for fun, leading to this:

```
local function getNeededVars(tab,func)
    local needed,this = {}
    this = setmetatable({},{
        __index = function(s,k)
            -- See if the requested variable exists.
            -- If it doesn't, we obviously complain.
            -- If it does, we log it and return the value.
            local var = tab.vars[k]
            if not var then
                error("Eh, "..k.." isn't registered (yet?)",5)
            end needed[k] = true return tab.vals[k]
        end;
    }) func(this) return needed
end

local function updateStuff(self,key,done)
    for k,v in pairs(self.levars) do
        if v.needed and v.needed[key] then
            if not done[v] then done[v] = true
                self.vals[v.name] = v.func(self)
                updateStuff(self,v.name,done)
            end
        end
    end
end

local function createSubTable(self,key,tab)
    return setmetatable({},{
        __newindex = function(s,k,v)
            tab[k] = v updateStuff(self,key,{})
        end; __index = tab;
    })
end

local dependenceMeta
dependenceMeta = {
    __index = function(self,k)
        -- Allow methods, because OOP
        local method = dependenceMeta[k]
        if method then return method end
        local variable = self.vars[k]
        if not variable then
            error("Variable "..k.." not found",2)
        end return self.vals[k]
    end;
    __newindex = function(self,k,v)
        local variable = self.vars[k]
        if not variable then
            error("Use :Register() to add stuff",2)
        elseif type(v) == "table" then
            self.vals[k] = createSubTable(self,k,v)
            return updateStuff(self,k,{})
        end self.vals[k] = v updateStuff(self,k,{})
    end
}
function dependenceMeta:Register(var,value)
    local varobject = {func=value,name=var}
    self.vars[var] = varobject
    table.insert(self.levars,varobject)
    if type(value) == "function" then
        varobject.needed = getNeededVars(self,value)
        self.vals[var] = value(self)
    elseif type(value) == "table" then
        self.vals[var] = createSubTable(self,var,value)
    elseif value then
        self.vals[var] = value
    end
end
function dependenceMeta:RegisterAll(tab)
    for k,v in pairs(tab) do
        self:Register(k,v)
    end
end

local function DependenceTable()
    return setmetatable({
        levars = {};
        vars = {};
        vals = {};
    },dependenceMeta)
end

local test = DependenceTable()
test:Register("border",{
    x=20; y=50;
    height=200;
    width=100;
})
test:Register("body",function(self)
    return {x=self.border.x+1,y=self.border.y+1,
        height=self.border.height-2,
        width=self.border.width-2}
end)
test:Register("font",function(self)
    local size = (self.body.height+2)-(math.floor((self.body.height+2)/4)+1);
    return { size = size; -- Since we use it in the table constructor...
        height = size-4; --love.graphics.setNewFont( self.font.size ):getHeight();
        -- I don't run this on love, so can't use the above line. Should work though.
    }
end)
test:Register("padding",function(self)
    local height = math.floor(self.border.height*(2/29))
    return { height = height; width = height*3 } -- again dependency
end)
test:Register("text",{input=""}) -- Need this initially to keep input
test:Register("text",function(self)
    return { input = self.text.input;
        centerHeight = math.ceil(self.body.y+((self.body.height-self.font.height)/2));
        left = self.body.x+self.padding.width+self.padding.height;
    }
end)
test:Register("backspace",{key = false, rate = 3, time = 0, pausetime = 20, pause = true})
-- Again, didn't use gui.id() on the line below because my lack of LÖVE
test:Register("config",{active=true,devmode=false,debug=false,id=123,type='textbox'})

print("border.x=20, test.text.left="..test.text.left)
test.border = {x=30; y=50; height=200; width=100;}
print("border.x=30, test.text.left="..test.text.left)
test.border.x = 40
print("border.x=40, test.text.left="..test.text.left)
```

It's a lot of code, but I liked writing it. It gives this nice output:

```
border.x=20, test.text.left=73
border.x=30, test.text.left=83
border.x=40, test.text.left=93
```

All properties only get recalculated when one of its dependencies is edited. I made it also work with subtables, which was a bit tricky, but at the end actually seems quite easy. You can edit *(for example)* the *body* field by setting it to a completely new table or by setting a field in the already existing table, as seen in the last few lines of the code snippet. When you assign it to a new table, it'll set a metatable on it. You can't use pairs (& co) neither, unless you use 5.2 and can use __pairs.

It might solve your problem. If not, I had fun writing it, so at least it'll always be something positive that I wrote this. *(And you have to admit, that's some beautiful code. Well, the way it works, not the actual formatting)*

**Note**: If you're gonna use it, uncomment the *love.graphics* and *gui.id* part, as I don't have LÖVE and I obviously had to test the code.

Here's a quick "summary" of my thing's API, as it might be confusing in the beginning:

```
local hmm = DependenceTable() -- Create a new one
print(hmm.field) -- Would error, "field" doesn't exist yet

-- Sets the property 'idk' to 123.
-- Everything except functions and tables are "primitive".
-- They're like constants, they never change unless you do it.
hmm:Register("idk",123)
-- If you want to actually set a regular table/function, you
-- can register a random value, then do hmm.idk = func/table
-- (the "constructor registering" only happens during :Register())

-- Sets the field to a constructor, which first gets validated.
-- During registering, the constructor is already called once.
-- Afterwards, it'll get called when it has to update.
-- (Whenever 'idk' changes, since 'field' depends on 'idk' here)
hmm:Register("field",function(self) return self.idk+1 end)
-- This errors because 'nonexistant' isn't reigstered yet
hmm:Register("error",function(self) return self.nonexistant end)
-- Basicly calls hmm:Register() twice with key/value as parameters
hmm:RegisterAll{
    lower = function(self) return self.field - 5 end;
    higher = function(self) return self.field + 5 end;
}
-- This sets the property 'idk' to 5.
-- Since 'field' depends on this property, it'll also update.
-- Since 'lower' and 'higher' depend on 'field', they too.
-- (It happens in order, so there should be no conflicts)
hmm.idk = 5
-- This prints 6 since 'idk' is 5 and 'field' is idk+1
print(hmm.field)
```

You could use setfenv (if Lua 5.1) to remove the need of 'self.FIELD'. With some environment magic you can have the constructor for 'field' *(as an example)* just be `function() return idk+1 end`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of metatables, more specific, the __newindex field:

*(Well, need to combine it with the __index field, but eh)*

```
function new(x, y, width, height )
    local object = {
        font = {}, padding = {}, text = {input=''}, -- tables themself are static
        -- also I assume text.input will change and has to stay the way it is
    }
    -- more static data here (yes yes, I know. The code is a bit ugly, but if it works fine...)
    object.config = { active = true, devmode = false, debug = false, id = gui.id(), type = 'textbox' }
    object.backspace = {key = false, rate = 3, time = 0, pausetime = 20, pause = true}
        object.border = { x = x, y = y, width = width, height = height }
    -- stuff that has to be calculated from the above variables goes below
    local border = object.border
    local function calculate()
        --border
        --body
        object.body = { x = border.x+1, y = border.y+1, width = border.width-2, height = border.height-2 }
        --font
        object.font.size = height-(math.floor(height/4)+1)
        object.font.height = love.graphics.setNewFont( object.font.size ):getHeight()
        --padding
        object.padding.height = math.floor(object.border.height*(2/29))
        object.padding.width = object.padding.height*3
        --text
        object.text.centerHeight = math.ceil(object.body.y+((object.body.height-object.font.height)/2))
        object.text.left = object.body.x+object.padding.width+object.padding.height
        --backspacing
        --config
    end
    calculate()
    local proxy = setmetatable({},{
        __index = object; -- proxy.abc returns object.abc (to get width, use proxy.border.width)
        __newindex = function(s,k,v)
            -- fires whenever 'proxy[k] = v' is done
            -- I assume you'll only change x/y/width/height, as other properties are dynamic
            -- Doing 'proxy.x = 123' is the same as 'object.border.x = 123' + recalculating
            object.border[k] = v -- Actually apply the change
            calculate() -- Recalculate the other properties that depends on the above
        end;
    })
    gui.add(object)
    return object.config.id
end
```

You can run code like `proxy.x = 12` to edit the X property. All values will be recalculated. It's not the best, but your code a *tiny bit* annoying to improve. *(But hey, if it works fine for you, it's good)*

**Note**: You can only set *x*, *y*, *width* and *height*. You can get all properties the old way though, e.g. *proxy.padding.width* ***(Mind that proxy.x doesn't work. Use proxy.border.x)***

Comment: redefining x/w/width/height are the least of my problem as i could just recall the original function using the new value i want to give. then replacing the entire index in the table where it's stored.